# Regex for random order of letters in a string?

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way using regex in Python to see if certain letters in a string are in another string, if they are in a different order? For example:

```
            if re.search('kol', 'opqlakoq'):
                print ('true')
            else:
                print('not found')
```

This should print true because all of the characters are in the string: opq**l**a**ko**q.

Comment: Does it _need_ to be a regular expression? Why not e.g. `all(char in 'opqlakoq' for char in 'kol')`?

Comment: Yes: `re.search('(?=.*k)(?=.*o)(?=.*l)', 'opqlakoq')`

Comment: This is a legitimate question and shouldn't have been so officiously downvoted until reasonable proof that it is wrong-headed. Please try to explain *why* you want to use a regex here.

Answer (score 1):

Use sets!

```
if set('kol').issubset('opqlakoq'):
```

Comment: As a minor note, if case is not an issue, `if set('kol'.lower()).issubset('opqlakoq'.lower()):` helps with that.

Answer (score 1):

Using a set (as suggested by @kindall) is the superior approach.

However, if there's some special reason for using a regular expression then:

```
import re

def search(this, that):
    p = re.compile(''.join([f'(?=.*{c})' for c in this]))
    return p.search(that) is not None

print(search('kolt', 'opqlakoq'))
print(search('kol', 'opqlakoq'))
```

**Output:**

```
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a Dictionary for incredibly fast lookups, in this caste it is vastly preferrable to a compiling Regex. in addition Regex might have to change dramatically if your requirements change and this will work for any two strings and is far easier to tweak for example if you needed to add a third string it would be very simple to do so.

```
def contains_characters(search1, search2):
    Charactercount = {}
    for character in search1:
        if character in Charactercount :
            Charactercount [character] = Charactercount[character] + 1
        else:
            Charactercount [character] = 1
    for character in search2:
        if character in Charactercount :
            Charactercount [character] = Charactercount[character] - 1
            if Charactercount [character] < 0:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    return True
```